# Why does bluetooth headset auto dial a number when I press the button

Tags: bluetooth, phone-app, bluetooth-hsp

After I have paired a bluetooth headset, if I press the call button on the headset it automatically calls one particular number? Why does this happen?
I would have thought it should bring up the dialer for me to select who to call.

I'm running a HTC Magic with 2.3 Gingerbread if that matters.

Comment: I don't think this is an Android issue. Unfortunately, there is no bluetooth.stackexchange.com. (It would have been on topic for the late lamented gadgets.stackexchange.com, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It call the last number used in or out, its supposed to be a quick reconnect after a dropped call...

The the BT is supposed to be hands free, so using the phone to select a call is none hands free!

You should be able to double tap the button and get a voice recognition control, with various occasionally funny results

Answer (score 2):

This is probably determined by your particular headset, not your phone.  I have two different headsets and the call button does two completely different things when pressed.